# Wamp failure to start/ orange icon

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I just installed Wamp servers and i have a problem. The icon stays orange.
So far, i checked port 80, hosts in windows/system32/drivers/etc/, httpd.conf, and the apache modules that are needed.
Any idea on what I might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: any other database or server might be causing problem ? have u configured any other server ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey I was having this problem, and I tried the responses relating to Skype, microsoft C++ x86 pack etc and nothing was working.

I clicked on the systray Wamp icon, under Apache/Service I noticed the Start&Stop&Restart were grayed out with Install service available. I had overlooked this previously because it didnt make sense that the wamp install wouldn't have went ahead with installing all 3 components. for some reason it had not though, all i had to do was click on Install service, a popup confirmed port 80 was open, and proceeded.
then my wamp icon went green.

maybe this will help some. was a real "duh" moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Skype running, open options, go to advanced then connection and uncheck "Use port 80".

Comment: Have you restarted Skype, and then restarted wamp?

Comment: Yes, skype is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved this a couple of days ago. Had a problem with vcredits not being correctly installed

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might have this question, in my case, what solved this issue was going to all services (by typing 'services.msc' in command prompt) and then stopping Windows' Web Deployment Agent Service. After that, restarting my server worked.